Does convolution preserve local integrability in the sense that if $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}$ and $g \in L^1$, then $f \ast g \in L^p_{\text{loc}}$?
Consider the Euclidian space $\mathbb R^n$, where $n \in \mathbb N$ is a fixed integer, equipped with the Lebesgue measure. Let $L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$($1 \leqslant p < \infty$) denote the usual space of all measurable functions that satisfy
$$ \int_K |f(x)|^p \, dx < \infty, $$
for every compact set $K \subset \mathbb R^n$. Recall that, given two measurable functions $f,g : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, the convolution $f \ast g : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is defined by
$$ (f \ast g)(x) := \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x-y)g(y) \, dy, $$
provided that the integral converges pointwise almost everywhere in $x$.
Now, my question is pretty simple and seems like the usual Young's inequality for convolutions adapted for the space of locally integrable functions. More precisely, I would like to prove the following statement.

Claim. Let $1 \leqslant p < \infty$. If $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$ and $g \in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$, then $f \ast g \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$.

Below I provide my attempt, altought I wasn't very sucessfull.
Atempt. Suppose that $f \in L^p_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$ and $g \in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$ and fix a compact set $K \subset \mathbb R^n$. Simple calculations yield
$$ \int_K |(f \ast g)(y)|^p \, dy = \int_K \Bigg| \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(y-z)g(z) \, dz \Bigg|^p \, dy \leqslant \int_K \left( \int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(y-z)g(z)| \, dz \right)^p \, dy. $$
Now, applying Minokwski's inequality for integrals, we obtain
$$ \int_K \left( \int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(y-z)g(z)| \, dz \right)^p \, dy \leqslant \left[ \int_{\mathbb R^n} \left( \int_K |f(y-z)g(z)|^p \, dy \right)^{1/p} \, dz \right]^p. $$
But from here it seems impossible to continue.
Thanks for any help in advance.

As shown in the nice answer of daw, this is not true in this generality and I'd like to add another counterexample and a class of functions where it works.
Another counterexample: For general $n\in \mathbb{N}, 1\leq p\leq \infty$ we can take $g(x)=e^{-\vert x \vert}, f(x)=e^{\vert x \vert}.$ Then we have
$$(f*g)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{\vert x-y\vert } e^{-\vert y\vert} dy \geq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{\vert y\vert-\vert x\vert}e^{-\vert y\vert} dy =e^{-\vert x\vert} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} 1 dy =\infty.$$
Morrey-Campanato functions are our friends:
On the other hand, if you assume that $f$ satisfies the the Morrey-Campanato condition ($1\leq p<\infty$)
$$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n, r>0} r^{-\lambda } \int_{B(x,r)} \vert f(y)\vert^p dy<\infty
$$
for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, then we get that $f*g\in L^p_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. By your reasoning we get
$$\Vert f*g\Vert_{L^p(K)}^p
\leq \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \vert g(z)\vert \left[\int_K \vert f(y-z)\vert^p dy\right]^{1/p} dz\right)^p.$$
As $K$ is compact we find $R>0$ such that $K\subseteq B(0,R)$. Thus, we get
$$\Vert f*g\Vert_{L^p(K)}^p \leq \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \vert g(z)\vert \left[ R^\lambda R^{-\lambda} \int_{B(0,R)} \vert f(y-z)\vert^p dy\right]^{1/p} dz\right)^p.$$
Then we use the change of variables $s=y-z, ds=dy$ and the Morrey-Campanato condition to get
$$\Vert f*g\Vert_{L^p(K)}^p \leq \Vert g\Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)}^p R^{\lambda} \left( \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n, r>0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} \vert f(y)\vert^p dy\right) <\infty.$$
Of course, if one wants to be pedantic, it would be enough to impose the slightly weaker condition that there exists $R_0>0$ such that for all $ R>R_0$ we have
$$ \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} \int_{B(x,R)} \vert f(y)\vert^p dy <\infty $$
to ensure that $f*g\in L^p_\mathrm{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (however, the Morrey-Campanato spaces are well-studied and more widely used).

Very good. Thanks.

The convolution integral might not exist at all. Take $n=1$, $g(x) = min(1,|x|^{-3/2})$. Now let $f(x) = |x|^2$. Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f(x-y)g(y)  = \int_{\mathbb R} |x-y|^2
 g(y)  dy\\
\ge\int_1^\infty y^{-3/2} |x-y|^2 dy\ge \int_1^\infty y^{-3/2} (\frac 12 y^2 - x^2) dy=+\infty.
$$

Probably you'd like to pick $g(x)=\min{1, \vert x \vert^{-3/2}}$ to render $g$ integrable.

Or for another simple example, $g(x)=e^{-\vert x\vert}$ and $f(x)=e^x$.

@SeverinSchraven and daw, thanks for your discussion. Do you think anything can be concluded if we assume that we are only working with functions for which the convolution is well-defined ?

@xyz The convolution in this example is well-defined, just has a large singular set :) Are you interested in seeing whether one can get isolated singularities which are not in $L^p_\text{loc}$? Or what is your goal?

@SeverinSchraven Thanks for your information. Well, this is mostly about a result that is presented in an article. It seemed to me that the authors were using this fact implicitly but it turns out that it is not possible (based on your and daw's help). They have one further assumption on $f$ that might make the difference, thought. They are assuming that $f$ satisfies $$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, , r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|^p , dy < \infty. $$ Do you think that under this extra condition it is possible to guarantee that $f \ast g \in L^p_{\text{loc}}$ ?

@xyz What is the range of $\lambda$?

@SeverinSchraven Sorry, $0 \leqslant \lambda \leqslant n$.

Yes, that works. Pick a $R>0$ such that $K\subseteq B(0, R)$. Your last line is bounded by $$\left(\int_{\mathbb{R^n}} \vert g(z)\vert \left[ \int_{B(z,R)} \vert f(y)\vert^p dy \right]^{1/p} dz\right)^p \leq R^\lambda\Vert g\Vert_1 \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n, r>0} r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x,r)} \vert f(y)\vert^p dy.$$

Well, it should be a $\Vert g\Vert_1^p$. In any case, it is finite.

@xyz Sorry, forgot to tag you.

@SeverinSchraven thanks, corrected.

@daw I think now you are missing a square in the second expression.
